# Making additional data available in template context in django cms

Tags: django-cms

I have a django app with a form.

I'd like to make the form available in a django-cms page. How can I add it to a page context (specific page not every page).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it a plugin, register the plugin and use its `render` method.

See the [docs](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/how_to/custom_plugins.html).